# How can I install a keylogger software?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any free [keylogger software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) for Ubuntu. If yes, How can I install it?

Comment: You are not going to use that for spying I hope?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[logkeys [image: Install logkeys]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/logkeys) is available in the Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: This information need to be updated. I find no `logkeys` software in USC in 12.04

Comment: Older Ubuntu http://examples-static.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-setup-keylogger-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: Software center one doesn't seem to be updated. It has empty log file problem. You can download the zip file from this working and updated link http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/source/list and then make install.

Answer (score 4):

A simple google search would have yielded results!

http://blog.theunical.com/ubuntu/linux-keylogger-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Is there anything in Download Center?

Comment: t3ch, open up the software centre and start typing maybe something like "keylo.." in the search box, in the upper right corner. You seriously didn't look before you asked? Not to bang on about it, but it comes across as irreverent of our time. The package you're looking for is called 'logkeys' and it works very well indeed.

Comment: True, maybe a google search would have yelded results... but then of what value is **askubuntu.com**?  When questions are asked here they actually end up on google, otherwise askubuntu has no public face... I looked a t3ch's profile.. his questions seem to be quite valid and non-trivial (to me) and I don't think he deserves a caning over it..

Comment: I admit I should have googled first but I am very sure this question is going to help many newbies who come to askubuntu everyday.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a keylogger for ubuntu..

You can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkl/)

Or you install it via apt-get

Enable universe repositories,and then run the following in terminal

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install lkl
```

To run,type the following in terminal

```
lkl -l -k us_km -o log.file
```

for seeing results

```
tail log.file
```

Comment: there are definitely better keyloggers out there than lkl such as those stated above

Answer (score 1):

You can use LKL.
Download from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lkl/

**Steps to install:**

- Unzip or untar the file you have downloaded.
- Open the terminal and CD to the lkl location.
- Now type ./confiure and press ENTER to check all the required resources it needs are available.
- If you get any errors related to C compiler, for example: 'C compiler cannot create executable.'
- In case of C compiler error type: sudo apt install libc6-dev.
- Type 'make' and press ENTER to compile the package.
- Type 'sudo make install' and press ENTER to install the program.
- It should complete the installation.

**How to use?**

You can send argument with the command lkl

-h help

-l start to log the 0×60 port (keyboard)

-b debug mode

-k  set a keymap file

-o  set an output file

-m  send logs to

-t  hostname for sendmail. Default is localhost

Example: lkl -l -k us_km -o log.file // use USA kb and put logs in ‘log.file’