# `wc`-like command to count keystrokes

Tags: text

I need (in future regularly) to count the keystrokes (German: Anschläge) of *existing* texts. *This is not about calculating typing speed, but I need to calculate the length of the texts in ["norm pages"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normseite).*

These "keystrokes" differ from normal character count in that uppercase letters are counted as two keystrokes, and so are all characters that require shift to be produced on a standard keyboard layout (space, tab, enter/eol count as one keystroke as well).

Before writing a script on my own: is there anything like "`wc --keystroke`" around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but essentially what you want is a keylogger and based on the text file it creates to store what is logged you can count the letters in the log. But...it probably will register capital letters as 1 key. See [How can I install a keylogger software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14180/how-can-i-install-a-keylogger-software) for examples. Log the strokes and then do [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026214/counting-number-of-characters-in-a-file-through-shell-script) to count them

Comment: Sorry: purpose was unclear. I'm not measuring typing speed but need to calculate the length of already typed (ASCII converted from LaTeX / Word / pdf) documents in "norm pages" (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normseite). I think I'll put together a script that replaces the "2-keystroke characters" with two e.g. dots and then use `wc`. Thanks anyways.