# how to make sure my keys are recording to do some action?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any way I can make sure that , what ever the keys I am pressing for some shortcut are sending properly & later I can know them If i want ?

I will explain,  For example take a case as I would like to open my terminal so pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> can do opening a terminal for me. So my question is how can I know,  by pressing which keys that has terminal opened at that time ?

you can consider my Question as some log related issue too.

Comment: Think before giving downvotes/negative votes , If you dont understood the question just be it, some one else can understand it & answer it If they can.

Comment: Will a key-logger software be fine for this? If yes, have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14180/how-can-i-install-a-keylogger-software

Comment: @Jobin I have a question , did keylogger just going to record what I pressed or going to record what keys are processed for actions ?

Comment: A key logger only logs the keys pressed.

Comment: @Jobin ok Thank you , but I want more information like is it processed for some action or not.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is that there are many layers of applications which a key combination has to transverse for being applicable. To put an example:

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. First the Xorg server takes my keypresses and analyzes them, if it's not registered then it pass it to the next layer which is the Desktop Manager, if the desktop manager doesn't have any registered key combination like that, then it pass it to the current active window/application which is the end of the road.

If none of those layers recognize that key combination then it just sends the keypresses to be written. Is difficult to make an application that listen all those software layers and waits for events to be fired (there are some, but it's a overkill to debug all your running applications at the same time) at keypresses.

Comment: Ok I came to know some new depth concept today.