# How to have a daily statistic of keys pressed?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, software-recommendation, logging

I want to analyse how often I press a certain key in my daily typings and hence I would like to set up tracking of my keyboard. (It also might be the case I was challenged that the key I would press most often was the backspace and I would like to disprove that by hard facts.)

I am not interested in complete strings and those shouldn't be stored anywhere on disk. What I am looking for is not a complete keylogger and black hat use cases should at best be avoided.

My quick search brought up:

```
xinput --test-xi2
```

yet this is very raw:

```
EVENT type 13 (RawKeyPress)
    device: 3 (12)
    detail: 37
    valuators:

EVENT type 13 (RawKeyPress)
    device: 3 (12)
    detail: 54
    valuators:
```

and I would have to implement the statistics myself.

Is there any way I can have statistics of keys pressed?

Further search had me stumbeling upon [krefreq](https://github.com/bagder/keyfreq), yet I haven't looked that far into it.

Comment: I don't know of any automatic tool that does the statistics, but maybe you can [use a keylogger](http://askubuntu.com/q/14180/29595) and then  extract the infos from there. Indeed, what I would do is then just isolate the backspace, count the occurrences and then do the same for what you think the competitors are (I think that the most used would be space).

Comment: I think I've just passed the white belt to Orange belt. >.>

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

You could use [openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page) to define key bindings easily, to bind any key to an action:

```
 <keybind key="0x41">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>echo "A\n" >> keylog.txt</execute>
      </action>
 </keybind>
```

You can define your mappings in the rc.xml file and and run `openbox --reconfigure` to apply your new bindings. Each time if you pressed a key with respect to one of your mapping entries it writes the respective character to the keylog.txt file. At the end of the day if you are interested in how many times you stroke each key, count over the entries in the keylog.txt:

```
 sort keylog.txt | uniq --count
```

I know it fits not your requirements, because it saves the output at your hard drive and you have to calculate the quantities by your self. But it looks pretty simple and I don't know which kind of further statistics you are looking for. In my opinion you should reconsider what you are meaning if you said:

> I am not interested in complete strings and those shouldn't be stored
>   anywhere on disk.

What are your expectations how a program should handle all your key strokes, if it shouldn't store the input somewhere in file?

A further question comes up with the draft above. Is there a file in lubuntu 16.04 where openbox or the standard input (stdin) redirects to. I mean on which interface/port they listen for the current keystroke?